# is there anyway to access to Apollo Server from diffrent location?

Tags: server, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I made a server by apollo-server-express and solved to connect client to server on localhost.
by the way, I'm trying to connect to server from different location but when I tried to connect to server by my IP Address, the playground shows an error that says "Server cannot be reached".
however, these two locations are in the same network, same classes to C. So I assume that the problem is along to apollo server.

Comment: Does `PING <ip address>` work?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid yes it works!

Comment: and `Test-NetConnection -ComputerName <ip address> -Port <port>`? (from both the local and remote client)

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid yes... i just tried and works. it this possible that apollo could block the ip address and i should allow it to work?

Comment: show/explore dev tools network - OPTIONS (preflight) request failed? standard cors problem?

Comment: I solved it and the problem was logic.
I put something in the context which checks the token and it was causing error and i didn't make exception code.